# JSONWebTokenError: JWT Malformed at index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, graphql, jwt

I'll be honest, I'm totally lost on this. This project was working perfectly fine, and I'm running this from my last working GitHub push. Here's what happened. I lost my entire backend. Don't know how, not sure what happened. So when I pulled from GitHub I didn't have a backup of my JWT secret key. I got the "Invalid Token Error" (or something like that). I put this whole project on a new server/database and now I get the following error:

```
JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\glove\workspace\CharityApp\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:49:17)
    at C:\Users\glove\workspace\CharityApp\backend\src\index.js:15:30
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\glove\workspace\CharityApp\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\glove\workspace\CharityApp\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\glove\workspace\CharityApp\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\glove\workspace\CharityApp\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\glove\workspace\CharityApp\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at cookieParser (C:\Users\glove\workspace\CharityApp\backend\node_modules\cookie-parser\index.js:71:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\glove\workspace\CharityApp\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\glove\workspace\CharityApp\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
```

And the block of code it's referring to in index.js:

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
require('dotenv').config({path: 'variables.env'});
const createServer = require('./createServer');
const db = require('./db');

const server = createServer();

server.express.use(cookieParser());

// decode jwt to get user id on each request
server.express.use((req, res, next) => {
    const {token} = req.cookies;
    if(token) {
        const {userId} = jwt.verify(token, process.env.APP_SECRET);
        // put userid onto request for access
        req.userId = userId;
    }
    next();
});
```

And the sign code that's used multiple times whintin GraphQL resolvers involving signing in.

```js
const token = jwt.sign({userId: user.id}, process.env.APP_SECRET);
    // set cookie with token
    ctx.response.cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge
});
```

The app secret just pulls from a .env file and the maxAge is just a simple const for a 1-year cookie.

This was basically a finished project. :/ If someone can help me out on it, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you cleared your cookies in the browser since changing the secret? You really only should receive that error if the value you pass to `verify` is a string but it's not actually a JWT. You can log the value for `req.cookies.token` to the console to see if it looks like a valid JWT.

Comment: It would be that simple wouldn't it? Haha, yes, I cleared the cookies and it's working fine. :) Thanks man.

Comment: And the console log is looking like a valid JWT with the three sections. Good stuff, I'm back in business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the secret for your JWT on the server, you'll end up invalidating any existing JWTs your server previously issued. If the JWT is saved as a cookie, the browser will continue to submit the cookie with the now invalid JWT until the cookie expires or is deleted. You should [delete the cookie in question](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647) or clear all your cookies in order to fix the issue on the client side.

In this case, your secret was lost. It's not unreasonable for secrets to change over time though. You should make sure you handle invalid gracefully (perhaps resetting the cookie when this happens) in order to avoid a bad user experience when your secret does change. As a user, I can handle coming back to a site and finding that I've been logged out -- but having all my requests fail for no reason makes for a bad time. Even better, you can rotate your secrets, keeping track of the previous secret as well the current one and checking against both until you're certain any old cookies have expired.